# Visual Studio 2017: Replace vsdiffmerge by code compare does not work

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I tried to replace the Visual Studio difftoo "vsdiffmerge" by "code compare". 
For this I replaced in c:\users\heckner.gitconfig the reference to vsdiffmerge to codecompare like

```
[core]
    autocrlf = true
[user]
    name = My Name
    email = my.name@domain.com
[diff]
    tool = vsdiffmerge
[difftool]
    prompt = true
[difftool "vsdiffmerge"]
    cmd = \"C:\\Program Files\\Devart\\Code Compare\\CodeCompare.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" 
    keepBackup = false
[merge]
    tool = vsdiffmerge
[mergetool]
    prompt = true
[mergetool "vsdiffmerge"]
    cmd = \"C:\\Program Files\\Devart\\Code Compare\\CodeCompare.exe\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$BASE\" \"$MERGED\" //m

    keepBackup = false
    trustExitCode = true
```

But still Visual Studio uses vsdiffmerge when I double click on a change in Team Explorer.
When I issue on cmd shell wihtin my repo a git config --list I see the changes above apply.
When I change my name in the .gitconfig file the changed name shows up in Visual Studio under  Global Settings:

[image]

Anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the setting with this. This worked for me:

```
[diff]
    tool = codecompare
[difftool]
    prompt = true
[difftool "codecompare"]
    cmd = \"C:\\Program Files\\Devart\\Code Compare\\CodeCompare.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" 
    keepBackup = false

[merge]
    tool = codecompare
[mergetool]
    prompt = true
[mergetool "codecompare"]
    cmd = \"C:\\Program Files\\Devart\\Code Compare\\CodeCompare.exe\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$BASE\" \"$MERGED\" //m
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a **local** git config file which overrides the **global** one.

For example, by mistake I clicked on "Use Visual Studio": [image: Git Repository Settings]

And I was not able to use Code Compare anymore. But I found this in Code Compare website:

**Note:** The global gitconfig file is located in C:\Users\MyLogin.gitconfig. The config file for a local repository is located in repository root in the ".git" folder (this folder is hidden by default).

So to fix the issue, I had to edit the **.git/config** file located in the root of the project, which was overriding the global config.